# Is it possible to operate on multiple txt files at once in python?

Tags: python, numpy, data-analysis

I have 1080 .txt files, each of which contain over 100k rows of values in three columns. I have to perform an average of the first column in each of these .txt files.

Any method that performs looping is proving to be too slow as only one file is loaded by `numpy.loadtxt` at a time.

The kicker is that I have 38 of these folders on which I need to perform this operation. So 38*1030 files in total. Using `time` module to get compute time for each `numpy.loadtxt` gives me around 1.7 seconds. So the total time to run over all folders is over 21 hours which seems a bit too much time.

So this has me wondering if there is a way to perform multiple operations at once by being able to open multiple txt files and performing average on the first column. Then also being able to store that average in the corresponding order of the txt files, since the order is important.

Since I am a begineer, I'm not sure if this even is the fastest way. Thanks in advance.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import glob
    import os

    i = 0 
    while i < 39:

        source_directory = "something/" + str(i)    #Go to specific folder with the numbering

        hw_array = sorted(glob.glob(source_directory + "/data_*.txt"))  # read paths of 1080 txt files

        velocity_array = np.zeros((30,36,3))

        for probe in hw_array:

            x = 35 - int((i-0.0001)/30)         #describing position of the probes where velocities are measured
            y = (30 - int(round((i)%30)))%30

            velocity_column = np.loadtxt(data_file, usecols=(0))    #step that takes most time
            average_array = np.mean(velocity_column, axis=0)

            velocity_array[y,x,0] = average_array
            velocity_array[y,x,1] = y*(2/29)
            velocity_array[y,x,2] = x*0.5

        np.save(r"C:/Users/md101/Desktop/AE2/Project2/raw/" + "R29" + "/data" + "R29", velocity_array) #save velocity array for use in later analysis
        i += 1
```

Comment: Only viable solution to me is to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.

Answer (score 0):

Python has pretty slow I/O, and most of your time is spent in talking to the operating system and other costs associated with opening files.

Threading in python is strange and only provides an improvement in certain situations. Here is why it is good for your case. How threading works in Python is that a thread will do stuff if it has permission (called acquiring the GIL, or global interpreter lock. read about it). While it is waiting for something, like I/O, it will pass up the GIL to another thread. This will allow your files to be operated on (averaging the first row) while it has the GIL, and while the file is being opened it will pass the GIL on to another file to perform operations

Answer (score 0):

It's completely possible to write a function that loads files from a directory, and spawn off one `multiprocessing` and get it done in close to 1/39th the time it was taking. Or, don't parallelize by directory, but by file and queue up the work and read from that work queue.

Some pseudocode:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()

workers = []
for d in os.listdir("."):
  for f in os.listdir(d):
    workers.append(pool.apply_async(counter_function_for_file, (os.path.join(d, f),))

s = sum(worker.get() for worker in workers)
```

...and put your code for reading from the file in that `counter_function_for_file(filename)` function.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the purpose of `sum` in the last line? I'm trying to run this on a folder, parellelising by files read, and receiving a TypeError with unsupported operand types for +: `int` and `nonetype`. Running the function I have created in a loop without `multiprocesssing` runs without such error.

Comment: Ah, I was making progress on your averaging task and making assumptions about it.

Comment: Every function call has to return a number if you're summing them. You can't have some return None or not return (and thus return an implicit None) -- files with nothing would be of value zero, for the sum..